# Can't log into USPS website with sendkeys

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver

I'm writing a C# scraper so I can download my delivery receipts. I'm trying to use findelement and sendkeys/click to login to the usps website https://reg.usps.com/entreg/LoginAction_input . 
When I attempt this method, I get an invalid login error. I know the code works because I login other sites using the same method or even through JAVASCRIPTEXECUTOR.
In my current workaround, I have to TAB over to the input field and call inputsimulator. However,  I want to make my application headless which will not play well with InputSimulator as it as not tied to the selenium driver browser so I would really like to use sendkeys or another alternative. I have also tried to use javascript executor without any luck. Please help. Thank you.

Comment: Use [`HttpWebRequest`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httpwebrequest?view=netframework-4.8) for web scraping, not SendKeys.  SendKeys is going to be inherently unreliable.

Comment: You will also need Telerik Fiddler, so that you can examine the traffic going over the wire and mimic it in your code.

Comment: I'm not too good with tying in HttpRequest with the selenium webdriver. Can you point me in the right direction for researching this?

Comment: You won't need the Selenium Webdriver either.

Comment: Obtain Telerik Fiddler and look at the POST request that occurs when you log in.  Chances are good you can simply mimic this POST request.  Fair warning: it's going to take awhile to learn how to do this.

Comment: I have a little experience with Post requests and will try accessing the site through this method. this was one of the alternatives I have not yet thoroughly explored. Will get back to you with the outcome. Thank you